# Centralizar (usar apenas um) um try-catch para toda aplicação WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exceção, try-catch

Existe alguma forma de centralizar um `try-catch` para toda aplicação em uma aplicação WPF com C#?

Eu criei uma janela para usar como `MessageBox` personalizada. Quando der algum erro em qualquer cadastro do sistema o erro, tem como sempre cair no mesmo `try-catch` para não precisar colocar esta captura em todos os eventos da aplicação?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normalmente a recomendação é usar [`Application.DispatcherUnhandledException Event`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0):

```
public App() :base() {
    this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
}
public partial class App : Application {
    void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        // Faz o que quiser aqui.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Outra forma que pode ser usada se quiser fazer uma última ação quando já está desmontando o WPF:

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
public static void Main() {
    WpfApplication1.App app = new WpfApplication1.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    try {
        app.Run();
    } catch (Exception ex) { //aqui é um bom local para por esta captura geral
        //faz algo aqui
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WPF/CentralCatch.cs).

Se tiver um método [`onStartup()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.onstartup?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Application_OnStartup_System_Windows_StartupEventArgs_) na classe derivada de `Application`, pode ser um bom local para colocar algo também. Depende de como foi construído.

Realmente não deve ficar espalhando `try-cath` por toda aplicação. Mas tem lugar que precisa. Isso é a última medida, é quando tudo falhou, quando não tinha na para resolver de forma mais específica. E muitos erros são assim mesmo. Mas não ache que fez isso, não precisa mais se preocupar com manipulação de exceções de forma localizada. Aí seria o radicalismo ao contrário do que o pessoal costuma fazer.

O que até dá para fazer é criar uma biblioteca de ações comuns que devem ser executadas quando uma exceção ocorre, então chamar estas ações dentro do `catch` adequado. As pessoas costumam esquecer que "qualquer" coisa no código que vai executar mais de uma vez deveria fazer parte de uma biblioteca, deveria ser generalizada, seja para eliminar a repetição, seja para ficar mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Mas a captura da exceção deve ser mais localizada mesmo. A exceção deve ser capturada no momento certo, nem antes e nem depois do melhor momento.

O `try-catch` é uma estrutura que controla o fluxo da aplicação, então não pode ser colocado em qualquer lugar. E ele é até mais complicado que outras estruturas porque ele pode produzir efeitos colaterais globais. É preciso muito cuidado com seu uso.

É claro que não precisa colocar em todo lugar, este é o erro comum. E quase sempre as exceções não serão lançadas na parte do WPF em si.

Se estiver com dúvidas sobre o uso correto, vai ter que fazer perguntas específicas quando estiver usando em cada situações duvidosa, até se acostumar.

Comment: Obrigado funcionou perfeitamente. Eu usei o primeiro exemplo. Para exibir a mensagem de erro para o usuário eu posso usar o e.Exception.Message.ToString();  e para gravar no banco posso usar o e.Exception.StackTrace.ToString() e e.Exception.Message.ToString();?